# Netbeans: string not displaying

Tags: java, string, textbox

I want to display string in `textbox` of `vpsfame` class below my code, but I am unable to dispaly it. Can you give me suggestion this string in `new8` class show in code and serial class gives me string from gps continue. It also displays it at run time via System.out.println, but does not display it through the `textbox` of `vpsfame` class

package vpspro;

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Serial
{
public void com() throws UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException, TooManyListenersException
{
int c=1;

String wantedPortName="COM6";

Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

CommPortIdentifier portId = null;  
while(portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
{
    CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
    if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
       pid.getName().equals(wantedPortName)) 
    {
        portId = pid;
        break;
    }
}
if(portId == null)
{
    System.err.println("Could not find serial port " + wantedPortName);
    System.exit(1);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("system find gps reciever");
}
SerialPort port = null;
try {
    port = (SerialPort) portId.open(
        "RMC", 
        1);
    System.out.println("all are ok"); 
} catch(PortInUseException e) {
    System.err.println("Port already in use: " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}

port.setSerialPortParams(
    4800,
    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);



BufferedReader is = null;  


try {
  is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(port.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println("data is ok");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Can't open input stream: write-only");
  is = null;
}

String pt=null;
while(true)
{

String st = is.readLine();


        System.out.print("(" + c + ")");
        c++;
        new8 obj1 = new new8();

        obj1.decode(st);
        System.out.println(st);
        st = st.replace(st, "");


}

if (is != null) is.close();
/*if (os != null) os.close();*/
if (port != null) port.close();


}
}
```

this code for start communication with serial class

```
package vpspro;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;


public class getcon extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public getcon() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sc = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        br = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        help = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ok = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("select comport");

        sc.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "COM10", "COM11", "COM12" }));
        sc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                scActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        sc.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                scInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("select buad rate");

        br.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "4800", "1900", "150000" }));
        br.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                brActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        help.setText("help");

        ok.setText("ok");
        ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(sc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(105, 105, 105))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(ok)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(help)
                        .addComponent(br, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(sc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(br, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(help)
                    .addComponent(ok))
                .addContainerGap(118, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void brActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getSource()==br)
                br.addItem("4800");
                br.addItem("9600");
    }                                  

    private void scActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getSource()==sc)
            sc.addItem("COM6");
        sc.addItem("COM7");
    }                                  

    private void scInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getSource()==sc)
            sc.addItem("COM6");
        sc.addItem("COM7");
    }                                         

    private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getSource()==ok)
        {
            try {
                new Serial().com();
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getcon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getcon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TooManyListenersException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getcon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new new8();

        }
    }                                  


    public void getcom() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new getcon().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }                    
    private javax.swing.JComboBox br;

    private javax.swing.JButton help;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    public javax.swing.JButton ok;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox sc;

}
```

this code decoding my gps string and dispaly and hear problem created i can not dispaly below string in textbox when i rum program textbox are empty.

```
package vpa.io.*;
import vpspro.vpsfame;

public class new8
{
static String[] a2;
static String a1[];
static String c;
public static String[] t;

public void decode(String st)



{


    if(st.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("System has proble");
        vpsfame obj=new vpsfame();
        obj.ab.setText("ok");
    }
else
    {

 a1=st.split("\\$",0);

a2=a1[1].split("\\*",0);
checksum();


if(a2[1].equalsIgnoreCase(c))
{


t=st.split(",",0);



switch (t[0].charAt(0))
{
case '$':

String s=t[0].substring(3,6);


String s3="RMC";



if (s.compareTo(s3)==0)                                                    

{


System.out.println("                    NMEA 0183 Details.....");
System.out.println("System identity:                            "+t[0].substring(1,3));
System.out.println("NMEA Formate:                               "+t[0].substring(3,6));
System.out.println("(UTC)Time:                                  "+t[1].substring(1,2));
new vpsfame().ac.setText(t[1].substring(1,2));
System.out.println("Lattitude:                                  "+t[3]);


System.out.println("Direction of Lattitude:                     "+t[4]);
new vpsfame().ab.setText(t[3].concat(t[4]));
System.out.println("Longitude:                                  "+t[5]);
System.out.println("Direction of Longitude:                     "+t[6]);
new vpsfame().bc.setText(t[5].concat(t[6]));
System.out.println("Speed over Ground:                          "+t[7]);
new vpsfame().cd.setText(t[7]);
/*System.out.println("Track mode:                                 "+t[8]);
System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
System.out.println("DATE:                                       "+t[9]);
System.out.println("adjustment declination                      "+t[10]);
System.out.println("Direction of Magnetic variation:            "+t[11].charAt(0));*/





}


}

else
        System.out.println("                                    Invalid Formate...");
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("                                    Invalid DATA....");
}
}
else
System.out.println("                                            no match checksum");

}
}





public static void checksum()
{


int l=a2[0].length();
char[] a=a2[0].toCharArray();
int b=0;

for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{

b=b^a[i];

}

 c=Integer.toHexString(b);

}
```

}

and this is my main class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * vpsfame.java
 *
 * Created on Jan 26, 2013, 11:02:32 PM
 */
package vpspro;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



/**
 *
 * @author DHARMA
 */
public class vpsfame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public vpsfame()
    {
            initComponents();
    }

    /** Creates new form vpsfame */

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        ab = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        bc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ac = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cd = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        gc = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        lm = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem5 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem6 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem7 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem8 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ab.setEditable(false);
        ab.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                abActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("latitude");

        jLabel2.setText("longitude");

        bc.setText(" ");
        bc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bcActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("UTC");

        ac.setText(" ");
        ac.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                acActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setText("Speed of vessel");

        cd.setText(" ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 621, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 368, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        gc.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_G, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        gc.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DHARMA\\Desktop\\png\\20x20\\55.png")); // NOI18N
        gc.setText("get connection");
        gc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                gcActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(gc);

        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_T, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setText("track");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        lm.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_M, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        lm.setText("load map");
        lm.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                lmActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(lm);

        jMenuItem4.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem4.setText("data save");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem4);

        jMenuItem5.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_T, java.awt.event.InputEvent.META_MASK));
        jMenuItem5.setText("set time zone");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem5);

        jMenuItem6.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Q, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem6.setText("quit");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem6);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("view");

        jMenuItem7.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        jMenuItem7.setText("saved data");
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem7);

        jMenuItem8.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_A, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        jMenuItem8.setText("about us");
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem8);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(cd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35))
                    .addComponent(ab, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(ac, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(bc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(ab, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                        .addComponent(bc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(ac, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(cd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void gcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(evt.getSource()==gc)
        {
            getcon obj3=new getcon();
            obj3.setVisible(true);
        }

    }                                  

    private void lmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void abActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                  

    private void acActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void bcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */ 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException, TooManyListenersException {





    /*public vpsfame() 
    {


        initComponents();*/
        new new8();





        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


            public void run() {



                /*URL url=getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\DHARMA\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\vpspro\\src");*/
                vpsfame obj4=new vpsfame();

                new vpsfame().setBackground(Color.yellow);
                obj4.setSize(1000, 
                        500);


                ImageIcon image1=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DHARMA\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\vpspro\\src");
                System.out.println("jjdfhj");
                obj4.setIconImage(image1.getImage());
                obj4.setTitle("VPS");
                obj4.setVisible(true);
                new new8();




            }
        });

}
    /*public vpsfame()
    {
       fm=new JFrame("VPS");
        fm.setSize(1000, 1000);
        fm.setVisible(true);
        fm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }*/
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    public static javax.swing.JTextField ab;
    public javax.swing.JTextField ac;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField bc;
    public javax.swing.JTextField cd;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem gc;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem7;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem lm;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously advise you to take a time out, and refactor all of your code. Igonoring that in the class `new8`, in method `decode` replace this code:

```
new vpsfame().ac.setText(t[1].substring(1,2));
System.out.println("Lattitude:                                  "+t[3]);


System.out.println("Direction of Lattitude:                     "+t[4]);
new vpsfame().ab.setText(t[3].concat(t[4]));
System.out.println("Longitude:                                  "+t[5]);
System.out.println("Direction of Longitude:                     "+t[6]);
new vpsfame().bc.setText(t[5].concat(t[6]));
System.out.println("Speed over Ground:                          "+t[7]);
new vpsfame().cd.setText(t[7]);
```

With this:

```
//use one object, dont just create new frames
vpsfame myFrame = new vpsfame();

myFrame.ac.setText(t[1].substring(1,2));
System.out.println("Lattitude:                                  "+t[3]);
System.out.println("Direction of Lattitude:                     "+t[4]);

myFrame.ab.setText(t[3].concat(t[4]));
System.out.println("Longitude:                                  "+t[5]);
System.out.println("Direction of Longitude:                     "+t[6]);

myFrame.bc.setText(t[5].concat(t[6]));
System.out.println("Speed over Ground:                          "+t[7]);
myFrame.cd.setText(t[7]);

//Also set the frame to visible, so it can be displayed once you've done all this work.
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is that:

1. Firstly, you are creating multiple vpsframe objects where you should only have one. It makes no sense to create 5 frames where each will have 4 empty fields. Create one object and initialise all it's fields rather than using 5 diffrent objects.
2. You are not tracking the objects you are creating, the garbage collector will just get rid of the, so create one object, assign it to a variable and use that.
3. Set the vpsfame object to visible, otherwise you will never see it.

Your code also needs refactoring, you should be using the camelCase naming convention, and classes should always begin with Capital letters.

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion.i correct my decode method as per your suggestion but still not give desired output

Comment: @dharma11 Can you please describe what output you desire? From what i gathered above you want to display some text to a textbox? Its not very clear.